# checking login credentials to see if they are valid in Active Directory AND check to see if they are apart of a specific group in AD

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, active-directory-group

below is a method used to check to see if the Creds entered are good. i also would like to add on to this to see if they are part of group "XXX".

```
    Private Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Domain, Username, Password)
    Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
    Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel
    Try
        Dim Results As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne
        Success = Not (Results Is Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Success = False
    End Try
    Return Success

End Function
```

and below i tried to play around with stuff i found on stack but im not having much luck. how can i use existing method and add  to it in order to get my results?

```
Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal UserName As String) As Boolean
    'Dim MyIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = New WindowsPrincipal(New WindowsIdentity(UserName)) ' System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    'Dim userPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(New WindowsIdentity(Username))
    Dim MyPrincipal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(New WindowsIdentity(UserName)) 'New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(userPrincipal)
    Return MyPrincipal.IsInRole("XXX_YYY")
End Function
```

Also Tried to do something like this but getting the error i screenshotted.

```
Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal UserName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Result As Boolean
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://AD")
    Dim MemberSearcher As New DirectorySearcher

    With MemberSearcher
        .SearchRoot = de
        .Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN=VAL_ITS))"
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("Member")
    End With

    Dim mySearchResults As SearchResult = MemberSearcher.FindOne()

    For Each User In mySearchResults.Properties("Member")

        If User = UserName Then
            Result = True
        Else
            Result = False
        End If
    Next

    Return Result
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Project > Add Reference > System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement & System.DirectoryServices
```

Validate using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace

```
    Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

    Public function validate(username as string, password as string, domain as string)

        Dim valid As Boolean = False

        Using context As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain)
            valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password)
        End Using

        return valid

    End Function

    Public function checkgroup(domain as string, username as string, groupname as string)

      Dim isMember as boolean = false
      Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain)
      Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username)
      Dim group As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupname)

      If user IsNot Nothing Then
        If user.IsMemberOf(group) Then
          isMember = True
        End If
      End If

      return isMember

    End Function
```

Comment: Im importing System.DirectoryServices but Im not getting "PrincipalContext" to define itself. and it does not recognize AccountManagement

Comment: Add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, and then Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement